# Javascript: Pushing data to an array object inside for-loop

Tags: javascript, loops

For example I have an object looks like below.

I am push these already

```
for(var i = 0; i < result.length ; i++){
                        engagaement.push(result[i].engagement);
                        engagementPercentage.push(result[i].engagementPercentage);
                        name.push(result[i].name);
                        sovId.push(result[i].sovId);
                        volume.push(result[i].volume);
                        volumePercentage.push(result[i].volumePercentage);
                    }



var test3way = [
                    {y: engagementPercentage[0], numData : engagaement[0], id: sovId[0]},
                    {y: engagementPercentage[1], numData : engagaement[1], id: sovId[1]},
                    {y: engagementPercentage[2], numData : engagaement[2], id: sovId[2]},
                    {y: engagementPercentage[3], numData : engagaement[3], id: sovId[3]},
                    {y: engagementPercentage[4], numData : engagaement[4], id: sovId[4]}
               ]
```

And i tried to use for loop to prevent duplicate

```
    for(var i = 0; i < engagementPercentage.length ; i++){

        var test3way = [
            {
             y: engagementPercentage[i],
             numData : engagaement[i],
             id: sovId[i]
            },
        ]               
    }
```

But it doesn't looks like i am doing in right apporch, how should i correct it?

P.S Consider those arrays are look like `var sovId = [1,56,23]`

Comment: This question has been answered, more than once, on SO... 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229645/remove-duplicates-from-javascript-array

Comment: Your first code snippet refers to `sovId[i]` when there is no `i`?

Comment: You are declaring the array with each iteration of the loop. Declare the variable _outside_ the for loop, and `.push` your objects into `test3way`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code only defines `test3way` variable multiple times and having different property values each iteration of the loop. You can try array pushing.

```
var test3way = [];
for (let i = 0; i < engagementPercentage.length ; i++) {
    test3way.push({
         y: engagementPercentage[i],
         numData : engagement[i],
         id: sovId[i]
    }); 
}
```

Also on a side note, you should write `let i` instead of `var i` as the for loop iterator so that the scope is only within the loop.